# Is there a tool that comprehensively shows/manages all applications?

Tags: package-management

I am looking for something similar to Synaptic for debian packages, but a tool that manages not only debian packages, but also installed AppImages, flatpak, and snap.

I think it would be very nice to have just one tool/place to see and manage all that is installed.

The way it is now, when an app is updated, I can't recall how I previously installed it - Do I download the debian file, or the appimage, or the flatpak, in order to do the update?  So, I have to go hunting around in my system in order to know how I should handle the update.

So.....  Is there such a tool?

Comment: I think, for GNOME Software (or Ubuntu Software, which is based on the GNOME one) there are [plans to support snaps](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/snap-url-support-coming-ubuntu-software-app-plus-love-news), and it already has [some support for flatpaks](https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2016/07/05/flatpak-and-gnome-software/), and maybe [if there's interest](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/244), [appimages](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/58) as well.

Comment: The answer is not yet, but it is in the works.

Comment: @muru not  making that an answer?

Comment: @Rinzwind go ahead... I don't use GNOME Software, so I have no idea how good the support is.

Answer (score 2):

In **Ubuntu 19.04** ([it will feature the majority of Gnome 3.32](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/gnome-3-32-gives-users-more-say-on-what-apps-can-access)): A new ‘Applications‘ panel has been created by developers that offers users more control over the majority of locally installed applications, including Flatpak and repo apps, and on a per-app basis. 
Access is with `Settings > Applications`, it lists all installed applications ([repo and Flatpak, probably not AppImage but we will see](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/03/best-gnome-3-32-features)).
There is a button to `Open in Software` where you can uninstall it.

In **Ubuntu 18.04** the `Ubuntu Software` **shows** in the tab `installed` "regular" deb apps (installed in the `Ubuntu software` or via `apt get install` in a terminal), snap and flatpak apps but not yet AppImage apps ([see thread on the latter](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/58)).
And it let's you all also **install** snap apps as well as flatpaks app, but not yet AppImages (but [volunteers are welcome](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/244)).
When you click on an app, the details shows what source it uses:
[image]

**Snap apps** should be available and shown by default in the `Ubuntu Software`.
For **Flatpacks** you have to install a plugin. It is recommended to first add 
the **official Flatpak PPA** to be able to install Flatpaks. To install it, run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

The Flatpak plugin for the Ubuntu Software app (which is based on GNOME Software) makes it possible to install apps without needing the command line and to see the flatpaks in the `Ubuntu Software`. To install, run:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

You can add the Flathub repository to easily get flatpaks

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

To complete setup, **restart** your system. Now all you have to do is install some apps!
*Source: [Flatpak.org](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/)*

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You explained how the different types of packages are managed.  I already knew that, that wasn't my exact question.  Rather, my question was, Is there one single tool/application/source that will allow a user to have an overview of ALL applications installed, no matter the type of package(s) used?

Comment: I have not found what you said to be true.  For example, I have installed Lollypop via flatpak, yet in the Ubuntu Software tool under "Installed" it does not appear.

Comment: @dln949 Hmm, I agree this is not helpful. [Even in 2016 there was some support for flatpak](https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2016/07/05/flatpak-and-gnome-software/), therefore you would think it should be even better now. Could it be that it depends how you install the flatpak? Have you installed it directly from the Ubuntu Software with flathub-support? I installed Recipes like that and it shows up in the list (even with a label "source: dl.flathub.org" in the overview list).
I wish we had a better alternative but I have not heard of any yet. Maybe we will be nicely surprised some time.